Hard lines visible on curved surface
I have a cylinder which the geometry is making bad shading. The mesh is quads, I have done a data transfer, but then I lose the definition around the feature of the shape which is border shape.
I also add a bevel, but the lines around the border shape are zig zagish.
With the data transfer the condensed geometry looks smooth, but its ruining the nice definition.


With data transfer:

With the Bevel:


I'm not sure you'll have something correct with your method, you could redo it from scratch, begin with this flat mesh:

Select the outer edge loop, enable the addon called Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools and CtrlE > Offset Edges > Extrude, set the Width in the Operator Box:

Extend the mesh around:

Create these faces:

Give it a Simple Deform modifier, Bend mode, 360° on Z:

Extrude the slope inwards:

Bevel the edges:

Result:


Excellent method, thank you Moonboots!
